# mqtt client disconnected when subscribe with thingsboard topic

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosquitto, thingsboard

I am trying to make a connection with thingsboard by subscribing to a topic so that I can receive an updated state changes. But after subscription the client seems to be disconnected. Below is my code

```
const mqttEndpoint = 'MyLocalIpAddress:1883'
const MQTT_TOPIC = 'v1/devices/me/attributes'

const mqttClient = mqtt.connect(`mqtt://${mqttEndpoint}`, {
        username: '123456789asdf',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    })

    mqttClient.on('connect', function () {
        mqttClient.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
            console.log('subscribed')
            }
        })
    })
      
    mqttClient.on('message',  (topic, message) => {
        // message is Buffer
        console.log('topic', topic);
        console.log('message', message.toString());
        //this.server.emit('msgToClient', message.toString());
        mqttClient.end()
    })

    mqttClient.on('close', () => {
        console.log('mqtt: connection closed');
    })
```

I think the javascript mqtt code seems to be ok. But I am not figuring it out how can receive an update state from the thingsboard via mqtt.

The events in the console while running the above code:

```
Processing connect msg for client: mqttjs_f7181153!
Processing connect msg for client with user name: 123456789asdf!
Client connected!
subscribed
Client disconnected!
```

Also I had tried it with mosquitto but seems to be the connection is successful but not receiving anything if there is an update in state

```
mosquitto_sub -d -h "localhost" -t "v1/devices/me/attributes" -u "123456789asdf"
```